# Dissolve a table with no geometry QGIS return Null if any are Null

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, sql

I have a table without geometry that contains three columns: **Item**, **Sub-item**, and **amount**. I would like to create a new table with the sum of the amount of the sub-items that have the same Item attribute. (These categories are invented)

Normally I would use the GDAL Dissolve with the **Item** as the dissolve field. But in QGIS it doesn't accept layers without geometry as an input.

I have created dummy point geometry to get around this but feel like I must be missing something. Could I just be using an sql query? 
Also I would like it if any of the sub-items are null it would give me a null sum. Currently it only gives a null if all of the items are null.

Comment: you can use a virtual layer to run an sql query. Note that sum() ignores null except if ALL values are null

Comment: What do you mean by a 'table'?

Comment: Tabular data in a geopackage

Comment: First I've heard of that, but try the virtual layer sql query mentioned above. You're not dissolving geometry, you're grouping tabular data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer one of your needs, try using the `Aggregate` processing tool. You can select one column to group by and use a GUI to determine what aggregate functions to use, renaming columns and adding as many new aggregates as you like.

[image]

However it won't discard features or return NULL if a null value is found. You would need an SQL query via Virtual Layers for that.

---

If you want it to return a NULL for `sum(amount)` if your `subitem` column is null, you could try the following

```
SELECT 
item, 
group_concat(subitem) AS subitems, 
CASE WHEN 
    group_concat(coalesce(subitem,'NULLPLACEHOLDER')) LIKE '%NULLPLACEHOLDER%' THEN NULL
    ELSE sum(amount) 
    END AS sum 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY item
```

[image]

If you want it to return a NULL for `sum(amount)` if the `amount` column is null:

```
SELECT 
item, 
group_concat(subitem) AS subitems, 
CASE WHEN 
    group_concat(coalesce(amount,'NULLPLACEHOLDER')) LIKE '%NULLPLACEHOLDER%' THEN NULL
    ELSE sum(amount) 
    END AS sum 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY item
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting query.. however it works only if the 1st item in the list is Null. Else, it would be a regular sum() that ignores the null. It is relying on the way SqlLite allows using the 1st row value during an aggregation (which is forbidden in postgres) to decide on whether a Null or an aggregation will occur.

Comment: Good catch, I did think it was unusual behaviour and thought I got lucky. I've updated the query with an awkward alternative.

Comment: The Aggregate tool is great! Somehow I didn't know about it. Trying the virtual layers now. Do I need to replace nullplacehloder with something?

Comment: No you can use whatever you want for the text. Just make sure it's the same throughout the script. It basically concatenates all your values, with any null values replaced by a placeholder text, so that if the placeholder text is found in any grouping the result can be made null.

Comment: I set up the table just like yours and it is only giving me the item 3 in the output and not 1 or 2. I am using the add virtual layer interface but it looks like you might be using the database manager?

Comment: Yes it works in the DB Manager but not in the Add virtual layer interface

Comment: I was able to load it using Virtual Layer, but make sure you select No Geometry. I also didn't specify an unique feature identifier. I'm using QGIS 3.12

Comment: I feel like I should ask another question Called: Sum Grouped values and return null if any are null QGIS.  So you can answer it there and it can be found by future users. What do you think?

Comment: Do agree it may be a separate question, but not sure if that would be appropriate for GIS.SE as it is more of an SQL question (with variances for different dialects), and not strictly GIS

Comment: Yes selecting no geometry worked.

Comment: I changed the name of the question to include the Null aspect might be more discover-able  that way. Thanks for all your help!