# Equivalent of "Dissolve with stat" in QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, dissolve

I'm trying to sum multiple variables by categories (id of my polygons) within a QGIS model but I haven't found a proper way to do that...

If I hadn't to use the graphical modeler I would obviously use "Dissolve with stats" but this tool cannot be added within a model...

Is there another way to do such thing without using the python console ?

*Here is a picture of the attribute table of my shapefile:*
[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue recently https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362559/dissolve-a-table-with-no-geometry-qgis-return-null-if-any-are-null  I was directed to the aggregate algorithm which works great and is available in the modeler.

Comment: Hi Baswein ! The "aggregate" tool looks like what I'm looking for indeed ! 
I tried it but unfortunately, since I'm just learning QGIS, I'm struggling to get the sum of my two variables for each polygons' id

Comment: So you are trying to get for each ID  variable1 + variable 2 ?

Comment: I would like to get for each ID: sum of variable 1, sum of variable 2 (and ideally sum of variable1 + variable2 as well) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate should do exactly what you want.
Original Table
[image: original table]
Aggregate Setup
[image: Aggregate setup]
Expression for sum of var1 and var2
[image: Expression for sum of var1 and var2]
Final Output
[image: output]
The modeler interface will be a little different but try it outside of the modeler first.
Also have you looked at the group stats plugin?

Comment: Thank you very much Baswein ! :)

Comment: Glad to help out!